# How to scroll to the bottom right most of the page within Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying the below code to take the control to bottom right of the page but it is not working in my case.

```
Execute JavaScript | window.scrollTo(900,-900);
```

I tried other coordinates too, but still no success. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to handle an element located in bottom right corner?

Comment: window.scrollBy(900, 900) worked for me. Don't know why, I guess this should be used to access element on top right most of page, but this is working to access element on bottom right most of page

Comment: Removed my comment and created the answer to the problem!

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar, `(0, 0)` is top left corner coordinates (starting point), so the top right probably could be `(0, 900)`, bottom left- `(900, 0)`...etc. Obviously, none of coordinates could be a negative number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using

```
Execute JavaScript | window.scrollTo(900,-900);
```

Use this instead

```
Execute JavaScript | window.scrollBy(900, 900);
```

To help understand, and building on what Andersson said; the way your monitor works its coords is like a reversed graph

[image]

You start from the top left, and "add" to the right of the screen and then to the bottom of the screen.

0,0 being top left, and 1920,1080 being bottom right (given that you are using a 1080p monitor)

Any other problems please ask